# Companies doing Domain driven design

Tags: domain-driven-design

I've just finished reading Domain Driven Design and I'm enchanted with some of the ideas covered in it. Do you know any companies that implement ubiquitous language in their projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Domain Driven Design Yahoo Group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/domaindrivendesign/) may be a better place to find an answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

This is an indirect answer. You could find such projects by looking at software development companies who apply domain-driven design practices and seeing who their clients are.

Three such companies are:

1. [Domain Language](http://www.domainlanguage.com/) - at which Eric Evans works, he wrote the Domain Driven Design book
2. [Factor10](http://factor10.com/) - at which Jimmy Nilsson works, he wrote "Applying Domain-Driven Design and Patterns"
3. [OmegaPoint](http://www.omegapoint.se/) - employee Dan Bergh Johnsson has given a number of talks on DDD

Answer (score 2):

The Norwegian Oil and gas company Statoil uses it.

Answer (score 0):

The company I work for uses Domain-Driven Design to its fullest and after a few very successful projects, we're sticking with the design philosophy.

The company is [Hint Innovation](http://www.hintinnovation.com), we are a relatively new company so the website is not done yet, but it should be by January, you might want to check back then.

I don't know of any other company that uses the Domain-Driven Design approach for all of their projects.

Comment: Lol, though the wait page changed... I keep telling my bosses, but we're working hard on client projects, so creating and maintaining the website is not their main concern.

Comment: yeah but it's 2010 already, you are not telling your bosses often enough

Comment: @lubos hasko, Indeed, at least we're steadily growing and innovating.

Comment: It's up now! (has been for a few months actually, just slightly behind schedule).

Answer (score 0):

We've been using DDD at [Earnware Corporation](http://www.earnware.com/) for the last 2 years. Since we've been around for 10+ years, we employ the "anti-corruption layer" pattern quite a bit to talk to legacy systems.

DDD means a lot of things, but it also is something you can start doing right away with the next function you write (http://www.agileatwork.com/domain-driven-design-in-the-small/). It's about closing the gap between business concepts and your code so that your code can bend in the right spots. The patterns like [unit of work](http://www.agileatwork.com/unit-of-work-with-unity-and-aspnet-mvc/) and [specification](http://www.agileatwork.com/this-could-have-been-a-stored-procedure/) help accomplish that end result.

Answer (score 0):

Chillisoft has been doing Domain Driven Design for 10 years and have more recently developed [Habanero](http://www.habanerolabs.com/) an Enterprise Application Developement Framework that incorporporates many of the principles of Domain Driven Design and the many lessons learnt over the years.